# How to know if string is not equal to another iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I know that

```
if([string1 isEqualToString:string2]){}
```

BUT what about the other way around?

Comment: Actually, this was precisely my question and helped me a future visitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the different combinations:

- Test if strings are equal

  ```
  if([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) { /* equal */ }
  ```
- Test if strings are **not** equal (note the `!` operator that negate the condition)

  ```
  if(![string1 isEqualToString:string2]) { /* not equal */ }
  ```
- Alternatively, comparing the result to `NO` is equivalent:

  ```
  if([string1 isEqualToString:string2] == NO) { /* not equal */ }
  ```
- Finally if you need to do both tests and execute one code or another

  ```
  if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])
  {
    /* code to execute if strings are equal */
  } else {
    /* code to execute if strings are different */
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `!` operator:

```
if (![string1 isEqualToString:string2])
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the comparison explicit:

```
if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2] == NO)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's

```
if(![string1 isEqualToString:string2]){}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend previous answers, which are of course perfectly correct, you have to understand that `isEqualToString:` returns a **`BOOL`**, which can be **`YES`** or **`NO`**.

So:

```
if( [ s1 isEqualToString: s2 ] )
```

implicitly means:

```
if( [ s1 isEqualToString: s2 ] == YES )
```

So you can use:

```
if( [ s1 isEqualToString: s2 ] == NO )
```

which is the same as:

```
if( ![ s1 isEqualToString: s2 ] )
```